# PHP system language files, how can it be done?

Tags: php, translation

I currently have a web application that, based on what the user selects for the language, selects the correct language file to be used.

This language file contains many defined constants. Here is a snippet:

```
define("SHOP_LBL_PRODUCTS", "Products");
define("SHOP_LBL_ABOUTUS", "About us");
define("SHOP_LBL_CONTACT", "Contact");
```

This works as expected. Although, if I would like to make a UI for this, so that you, by a normal html form, can generate this whole file; I would need to:

```
1) extract the name and values from the current file 
2) write a file with php code (and replace the current file)
```

How would I do both of the above? Is it possible or is it a pure headache?

Are there any other way to do this? I am doing this since, the translator should not be sitting with a php file and all the define() calls.

Comment: No, the translator should be sitting there with a file format that's used for translations. The classic system here is gettext and is much preferable over constants.

Comment: It will be better if create different language file which have same constant & language specific value.

Answer (score 1):

When facing a similiar problem, I decided to use a different approach by using a MySQL Database. This way, storing, viewing and editing of the language-texts becomes quite simple. Changes and additions can be easily done with standard methods.
Your table-design could look something like this:

**Table1: 'text_label'**

```
text_id | text_label
```

**Table2-n: 'language_en'**

```
text_id | content
```

Using a JOIN Query, you could easily get the required content, based on the text_label.

For acces you could use a Static function, and the inclusion in your Script could look like this:

```
<?php echo Translater::get('Sample_text', 'en'); ?>
```

I am aware, that this differs to your questioned file idea, I am justleaving this here as a thought or Idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something similar to Symfony2 translation system?

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html

IMHO, YAML files are the best option for translation files.